# Ruby algorithm solving

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm

So I have a basic problem that needs to be solved. I need to take the following nested array [1, 2, ["str", 1], [[2]]] and return [1,2,"str",1,2]. Ultimately removing all nested arrays. The following is my incomplete solution:

```
test = [1, 2, ["str", 1], [[2]]]

def remove_array(array)
    new_array = []
    array.each do |item|
        if item != Array
            puts "you are here"
            new_array << item
        else
            remove_array(item)
        end
    end
end

remove_array(test)
```

This is a classic recursion method. However, I cant seem to think of how to maintain `new_array`. Every time I pass the item that is an array to it, `new_array` doesn't maintain its state. I would also like to point out that I am aware of the built in method `flatten` as I am trying to solve the solution without said method. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you trying to implement from scratch, or will a simple answer suffice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def my_flatten(arr)
  result = []

  arr.each do |el|
    if el.is_a?(Array)
      result.concat(my_flatten(el))
    else
      result << el
    end
  end

  result
end
```

You generally had the right idea, but you were never adding the inner array elements into your result.

Answer (score 2):

```
def remove_array(array)
  new_array = []
  array.each do |e|
    if e.is_a?(Array)
      new_array += remove_array(e)
    else
      new_array << e
    end
  end
  new_array
end
```

Comment: I understand what `+=` translates to, but I dont get how `new_array += remove_array(e)` preserves the state of `new_array`. Could you explain?

Comment: What do you mean by preserve the state of new_array? If array is [1, [2, 3]] and e is [2, 3], then at this point new_array is [1]. remove_array(e) returns [2, 3], so new_array += [2, 3] appends [2, 3] to [1], thus new_array becomes [1, 2, 3]. `+=` is basically the same as Array#concat.

Comment: The way you explained it makes sense on how the the result is retrieved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, there is a convenient built-in method called [flatten](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten)

It will "flatten" your array so that all the inside arrays disappear, and it returns one array with all elements inside

Edit:

Sorry editing this. Forgot that you were using recursion for your solution. Since you're essentially creating a new array each recursion, I'm not exactly sure how I would fix your solution at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `flatten` on you array.

```
a = [1, 2, ["str", 1], [[2]]]
=> [1, 2, ["str", 1], [[2]]]
   a.flatten
=> [1, 2, "str", 1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

just use the flatten! :) keep it simple..

```
test = [1, 2, ["str", 1], [[2]]]

def remove_array(array)
   array.flatten!
   return array
end

remove_array(test)

2.2.1 :024 >   remove_array(test)
=> [1, 2, "str", 1, 2]

I hope this helps everybody! Thanks
```